# How to install eZ Platform via composer

Tags: php, composer-php, ezpublish, ezplatform

**How do you install eZ Platform?**

I'd like to get starting using it and I hear that the best way is to use composer. The problem for me is I've not used either before :\

Note: *This is a first post to the new stackoverflow tag: [ezplatform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ezplatform). We needed this tag to be created for future support needs and want to ask a good and common first time user question make it clear to future users that they can use the [ezplatform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ezplatform) tag here on stackoverflow to ask questions specific to eZ Platform (and not eZ Publish). I realize that this is a rather poor quality first question for the tag and for that I do apologize. Please try to understand.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find full installation guide in official [documentation](https://github.com/ezsystems/ezplatform/blob/master/INSTALL.md#install). The only command you need is

```
curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php
php -d memory_limit=-1 composer.phar create-project --no-dev ezsystems/ezplatform <directory> [<version>]
cd /<directory>/
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a note here, you can also install eZ Platform with eZ Launchpad now https://ezsystems.github.io/launchpad/ (all on top of Docker)